# Qt 5.1 packages

Tags: 13.04, package-management, qt5

Is there any `ppa` containing Qt 5.1 prebuilt binary packages? I found [this one](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-daily), but it doesn't seem really well-provided.

I'm running Raring, but I see that even Saucy still has Qt 5.0.2.